# ¿Cómo evitar que el usuario introduzca el mismo valor dos veces?

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un programa en C el cual tiene como objetivo introducir números y almacenarlos en un arreglo, pero tengo como restricción que no se pueda ingresar dos veces el mismo número, ¿alguna idea de como restringir esto?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Aquí esta mi código:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
int n=0, num=0, i, j;
int N[n];
        printf("Escriba el número total de valores que se van a introducir\n");
        do {
           scanf("%d",&n);
           if(n<0)
              printf("Total de valores no validos, ingreselos de nuevo\n");
        } while (n<0);
        printf("Recuerda, los valores deben de estar entre 0 y 50\n");
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            do {
                scanf("%d",&num); //Si se ingresa un valor repetido muestre un mensaje y vuelva a solicitar el número
                if(num<0 || num>50){
                    printf("Numero no valido, ingrese de nuevo el valor\n");
                }else{
                    N[i]=num;
                    printf("- - - - -\n");
                }
            } while (num<0 || num>50);
            getchar();
            getchar();
            return 0;
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor tómate un momento y piensa el problema. **No tienes que ingresar números repetidos.** ¿Qué es lo que debes hacer? *Saber si el número ya está en el arreglo.* ¿Y cómo te das cuenta de eso? De la misma manera que tu cerebro lo hace. *Comparando cada elemento del arreglo con el que quieres saber si ya está en él.* Parece que ya sabes usar las estructuras necesarias para lograrlo. Haz un esfuerzo e inténtalo. Cree en ti misma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer un recorrido de todo el arreglo comparando valores, o guardar simultáneamente en ambos array (aunque creo que sería un gasto de memoria)
dentro del while hacer un for anidado que recorra el arreglo.
(cambié un poco el código porque había cosas que no me hacian sentido) espero que te sirva.

```
boolean bandera = true; //sirve para saber si el numero no se ha repetido
int comparar = 0;
 printf("Escriba el número total de valores que se van a introducir\n");

        //do {

           scanf("%d",&n);
           if(n<0)
              printf("Total de valores no validos, ingreselos de nuevo\n");

       // } while (n<0);
            else {
        printf("Recuerda, los valores deben de estar entre 0 y 50\n");
        for(i=0; i>= n; i++) {
                 scanf("%d",&num);
 
                 for(int j=0; j>= i; j++) {
                      N[j] = comparar;
                      if(comparar == num){
                          bandera = false;
                          i--;
                      }
                      else
                          bandera = true;
                 }
                   if (bandera == true){
      
                if(num<0 || num>50){
                    printf("Numero no valido, ingrese de nuevo el valor\n");
                    i--;
                }else{
                    N[i]=num;
                    printf("- - - - -\n");
                }
           } //bandera == true
           else{
               printf("Numero no valido, ingrese de nuevo el valor\n");
           } 
            } while (num<0 || num>50);
            getchar();
            getchar();
            return 0;
        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto fue lo que yo hice, analizalo y si no entendiste te ayudo. Con ayuda de un arreglo auxiliar puedo verificar que numeros ya introduje, y si detecta que ya se introdujo un nuevo numero, envia el mensaje
"No puede digitar el mismo numero dos veces";

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

```
int n,a[100],visto[100];
printf("Digite el numero de elementos: ");
scanf("%i",&n);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("\nDigite el elemento %i: ",i);
    scanf("%i",&a[i]);
    if(visto[a[i]]==1){
        printf("No puede digitar el mismo numero dos veces");
        i--;
        continue;
    }
    visto[a[i]]=1;
}



for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%i ",a[i]);
}


return 0;
```

}